# Spring Boot + Docker Compose: How to override 'Map<String, List<String>>' environment variable from yaml properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-properties

I am using yaml properties file for the sping boot configuration.

My structure of application.yml is following:

```
information:
  server: ${SERVER_INFO:devserver}
  config:
    "[http://www.myshop.com]":
      - Sam
      - Joe
    "[https://www.google.com]":
      - Mary
   ... other properties of Map type.
```

All this values basically represent structure `Map<String, List<String>>`
where **key** is **site address** and *List* is a **array of the users**. There could be many entries of this map, I am using this structure to read properties dynamicly.

How my docker container looks:

```
app:
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  build:
    ... i will skip this info
  image: testapp
  environment:
    - SERVER_PORT=8080
    - SERVER_INFO=QAAserver // overrided sucessfully
    - INFORMATION_CONFIG=?? // how to pass Map<Sting, List<String>> here?
```

So, basically, I need an ability to pass values of `Map<String, List<String>>` from docker compose env var to the spring boot, to override current value. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Objects are `Map<String, Object>` values.

```
    INFORMATION_CONFIG='{"[http://www.myshop.com]": ["Sam", "Joe"], "[https://www.google.com]": ["Mary"]}'
```

But you may want to use `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` for this

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.application-json

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but it does not work for me.  When I am using yml and using your solution, it does not work

Comment: But on the other hand idea of using JSON env variable in this case is acceptable. I will just change my yaml map to single property and after it I will process it.

Comment: Environment variables are not applied to the YAML by default. They'd need to explicitly be loaded using `${INFORMATION_CONFIG}`, as shown in the docs

Comment: Yes, but if I am not mistaken spring does provide an ability to override env variables by defaultm without ${}

Comment: No, I don't think so. You can refer the top of the linked externalized configuration documentation. Java System properties using `-D` JVM flags or `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` can be used without needing `${}`